# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception which I just cant figure out

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I simply cant figure out why I keep getting an indexoutofboundserror. I believe its pop up in the line

```
profits[i] = storeDays
```

The code is:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Business
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inputScanner;
        inputScanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the profit-calculation program.");
        System.out.println("how many days of data do you have?");
        int n = Integer.parseInt (inputScanner.nextLine());

    //call upon a function to store the profits into an array for further     use.
        double[] dayProfitList = inputProfit(n);
    //call upon a function to calculate average profit and its standard devation

    //calcAverageProfit(dayProfitList);


    }

        public static double[] inputProfit(int days) {
            Scanner inputScanner;
            inputScanner = new Scanner (System.in);

            System.out.println("input the profit on..");
            double[] profits = new double [days];

            for(int i = 1; i<days +1; i++) {
                System.out.println("day " + i + "?");
                double storedDays = Double.parseDouble(inputScan ner.nextLine());
                profits[i] = storedDays;
            }
            return profits;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are enumarated from **0** so the first element of it is **profits[0]**, next one is **profits[1]** and so on.

You are trying to reach an index that does not exist here:

```
for(int i = 1; i<days +1; i++) {
    ...
```

It actually should be

```
for(int i = 0; i<days; i++) {
    ...
```

Comment: I think it should be `for (int i = 0; i < days; i++) {...`

Comment: that does fix the issue however I would like it to work like
for(int i = 1; i<=days; i++) {

Comment: then you will need to create an array with **days+1** size like `double[] profits = new double [days+1];` and just forget about the first (zero!) element

Comment: And the 0spot will never be filled @AidanJBernstein and its a waste of memory. Trivial here obviously, but that simply isnt how arrays work in java, unless youre saving the 0spot for a special number.

Comment: I don't wish the value to change on days. I just want it to start off printing day 1 instead of zero.

Comment: Glad to help you. If the answer is fitting your question you can accept it [check out this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)